# C++ Random Number Guessing Game - Variable not declared errors

Tags: c++

So I have to create a Random Number Guessing game. I know there are other questions similar, but I would much appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction, please. I am very new to C++.

My problem seems to be that the variables are not being picked up in each of the difficulty functions. I get the not declared error.

Many thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int easy()
{
    srand(seed);
    randomNumber = 1 + rand() %12;

    cout << "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 12. Can you guess what it is?" << endl;
    cout << randomNumber << endl;
    cin >> userNumber;

    while (!win)
    {
        if (userNumber < randomNumber)
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Attempt " << numOfAttempts << ". " << userNumber << " is too low. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userNumber;
            playerScore -= 5;
        }
        else if (userNumber > randomNumber)
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Attempt " << numOfAttempts << ". " << userNumber << " is too high. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userNumber;
            playerScore -= 5;
        }
        else
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Congratulations. You guessed the correct number. It took you " << numOfAttempts << " attempts." << endl;
            cout << "Your score is " << playerScore << endl;
            win = true;
        }
    }
}

int medium()
{
    srand(seed);
    randomNumber = 1 + rand() %30;

    cout << "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 30. Can you guess what it is?" << endl;
    cout << randomNumber << endl;
    cin >> userNumber;

    while (!win)
    {
        if (userNumber < randomNumber)
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Attempt " << numOfAttempts << ". " << userNumber << " is too low. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userNumber;
            playerScore -= 5;
        }
        else if (userNumber > randomNumber)
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Attempt " << numOfAttempts << ". " << userNumber << " is too high. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userNumber;
            playerScore -= 5;
        }
        else
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Congratulations. You guessed the correct number. It took you " << numOfAttempts << " attempts." << endl;
            cout << "Your score is " << playerScore << endl;
            win = true;
        }
    }
}

int hard()
{
    srand(seed);
    randomNumber = 1 + rand() %50;

    cout << "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 50. Can you guess what it is?" << endl;
    cout << randomNumber << endl;
    cin >> userNumber;

    while (!win)
    {
        if (userNumber < randomNumber)
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Attempt " << numOfAttempts << ". " << userNumber << " is too low. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userNumber;
            playerScore -= 5;
        }
        else if (userNumber > randomNumber)
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Attempt " << numOfAttempts << ". " << userNumber << " is too high. Please try again" << endl;
            cin >> userNumber;
            playerScore -= 5;
        }
        else
        {
            numOfAttempts++;
            cout << "Congratulations. You guessed the correct number. It took you " << numOfAttempts << " attempts." << endl;
            cout << "Your score is " << playerScore << endl;
            win = true;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{

public:
    int randomNumber;
    int userNumber;
    bool win = false;
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    int numOfAttempts = 0;
    int playerScore = 50;
    int difficulty;

    cout << "Please choose a difficulty. 1 = easy, 2 = medium, 3 = hard." << endl;
    cin >> difficulty;

    switch(difficulty)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You have chosen EASY!" << endl;
        easy();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You have chosen MEDIUM!" << endl;
        medium();
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You have chosen HARD!" << endl;
        hard();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "You are playing EASY!" << endl;
        easy();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not useful to other users.

Comment: It looks like you have some serious, serious confusion regarding the declaration, initialization, and scope of variables, as well as C++ program structure in general. Probably oughta hit the textbook again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the variables that you are using in your difficulty functions are not declared in those functions.
You should pass them as parameters to these functions

```
int hard(int randomNumber, unsigned seed)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to make sense. This is a huge learning curve for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough. For example where is there the declaration of variable `randomNumber`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int easy()
{
    srand(seed);
    randomNumber = 1 + rand() %12;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//...
```

Or what does this mean?

```
int main ()
{

public:
    int randomNumber;
    int userNumber;
    bool win = false;
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    int numOfAttempts = 0;
    int playerScore = 50;
    int difficulty;
//...
```

The code is invalid from the syntaxical point of view. You should correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the error code gives you quite a bit of information (up until you get into template coding then there is another learning curve).  Your code has to many errors to even begin helping you without doing all the work for you.

Please copy and paste of better describe the actual error/warning messages too, not all of us have compilers at work to see what is going on.

Comment: I read the errors and tried searching up how to call the variables or make them public etc. I just couldn't understand how to do it, or what exactly I am looking for. I wouldn't come on here unless it was final resort. :)

Comment: More often than not, look at the first error only, the rest can and likely are caused by the first one.

I would highly recommend starting the project over, and every 5-10 lines (when you think it should compile at least) compile and fix errors and warnings as you go.  Do not ignore warnings either.

The code provided, more or less needs a re-write.

The functions, 'easy', 'medium' and 'hard' don't even return anything first off.  Nor do you capture the return values in the main function.  Nor have you defined seed anywhere it can be used by those functions.  I would say start over and go slow

Comment: Thanks Mike! I will take heed with your advice. :)